# java.lang.NullPointerException after second attempt

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
 private void jButtonStiahniActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
  //start the Rengine (JRI)
  String src,symbol1,symbol2 = null,title;
  REXP exp2;
  Rengine re = new Rengine(null, false, null);

  re.eval("library('quantmod')");
            if(!boolOanda){
               src="yahoo";
               symbol1=jComboBoxSymbols.getSelectedItem().toString();
               re.eval("kurz=getSymbols('"+symbol1+"',src='"+src+"')"); 
                exp2 = re.eval(symbol1+"$"+symbol1+".Close"); 
            }
            else {
                src="oanda";
                symbol1=jComboBoxSymbols.getSelectedItem().toString();
                symbol2=jComboBoxSymbols2.getSelectedItem().toString();

                re.eval("kurz=getSymbols('"+symbol1+"/"+symbol2+"',src='"+src+"')"); 
                exp2 = re.eval(symbol1+symbol2); 

            }

                   double[] kurz = exp2.asDoubleArray(); 

                        re.end();

       }
```

I got `java.lang.NullPointerException` at `double[] kurz = exp2.asDoubleArray();`  when I try to push this jButton **second time** . First time everything goes well, but for the second time I have exception. It seems like variable exp2 is null, but I dont understand why. Thank you in advance

Comment: Thank you guys, I finally solve it. I declared  
    Rengine re = new Rengine(null, false, null);
 as a class variable (or global) and its working.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the (perhaps flippant) answer is that *yes, `exp2` is null*.  Without knowing anything about this `REngine`, or what the logic of its `eval` method is, it's hard to add much more than that.  I can't even tell what the value of `boolOanda` is on the second invocation (or whether it changes from the first), so it's not clear which branch is executed to set `exp2`.

What I'd suggest is attaching a debugger to the process, then stepping through the method calls and seeing what's actually being invoked, and at what point the execution diverges from your expectations.

I would guess that *maybe* you mean to eval `symbol1 + '.' + symbol2` (currently both symbols are directly concatenated).  Or perhaps the input is simply entirely wrong, and the symbol variables are completely null on the second invocation. But as I said above, I don't really know what the dynamic model looks like here so ultimately you'd have to be the one to spot the discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

If exp2 is null, it's the result of one of these two assignments:

```
exp2 = re.eval(symbol1+"$"+symbol1+".Close");
```

or

```
exp2 = re.eval(symbol1+symbol2);
```

So, you need to do some debugging to figure out (a) which branch of the `if(!boolOanda)` was being executed, (b) what values were being passed to `re.eval`, and (c) why `re.eval` was rejecting them.